# How to connect 3 tables in Laravel migrations (Syntax error or access violation)

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, database-migration

I have limited knowledge of Laravel, PHP and MySql. I am trying to set up a database with 3 connected tables, using foreign keys. I did this manually in WorkBench MySql before, but I can't make it in Laravel. Here is my error and my code.

```
SQL STATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1072 Key column 'cat_id  
  ' doesn't exist in table (SQL: alter table `users` add index `users_cat_id  
  _usr_id_index`(`cat_id`, `usr_id`))
```

Table 1

```
public function up()
{
    Schema::create('users', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->increments('usr_id')->autoIncrement();
        $table->string('usr_email',45)->unique();
        $table->string('usr_password',256);
        $table->rememberToken();
        $table->string('usr_name',45);
        $table->string('usr_surname',45);
        $table->string('usr_title',45);
        $table->string('usr_psc',5);
        $table->string('usr_region',128);
        $table->string('usr_adress',128);
        $table->string('usr_tel',10);
        $table->string('usr_tel_int',13);
        $table->binary('usr_image');
        $table->tinyInteger('usr_type');
        $table->index(['cat_id','usr_id'])->nullable();
        $table->index(['tem_id','usr_id'])->nullable();

    });
}
```

Table 2

```
public function up()
{
     Schema::create('category', function (Blueprint $table) {
         $table->primary('cat_id');
         $table->string('cat_name',45);
     });
     Schema::table('category', function(Blueprint $table) {
         $table->foreign('cat_id')->references('cat_id')->on('users');
      });
 }
```

Table 3

```
public function up()
{
     Schema::create('team', function (Blueprint $table) {
       $table->increments('tem_id');
       $table->unique('tem_sub_id');
       $table->string('tem_name',45);
       $table->string('tem_subteam_name',45);

     });
     Schema::table('team', function(Blueprint $table) {
         $table->foreign('tem_id')->references('tem_id')->on('users');
      });

 }
```

Comment: If you have problems creating the migrations correctly I would recommend you to use http://laravelsd.com/ it's an online tool to generate the migraion files

Answer (score 1):

The error occurs because `cat_id` does not exist in your `users` table. Apart from that, there are some points to keep in mind when writing Laravel migrations:

- Unless you set [`FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS` to 0](https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/laravel/how-to-set-foreign-key-check-to-zero?page=1), you can only reference to existing tables, that is why I changed the order of creating your tables in my examples below.
- Keep in mind that, in order to make Laravel magic methods work, you should write your table names in plural form (users, teams, categories).
- Use 'id' for your id's (instead of 'usr_id'). Try to avoid using your table name as a prefix for your database columns.

Because Laravel Eloquent ORM heavily relies on standards, I would suggest to rewrite your tables in a fashion like I did below, following [Laravel Eloquent conventions](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/eloquent-relationships):

**Table categories**

```
public function up()
{
     Schema::create('categories', function (Blueprint $table) {
         $table->increments('id');

         $table->string('name',45);
         // etc... 
     });

 }
```

**Table teams**

```
public function up()
{
     Schema::create('teams', function (Blueprint $table) {
       $table->increments('id');

       $table->string('name',45);
       // etc... 

     });
 }
```

**Table users**

```
public function up()
{
    Schema::create('users', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->increments('id');
        $table->integer('category_id')->unsigned()->nullable();;
        $table->foreign('category_id')->references('id')->on('categories');
        $table->integer('team_id')->unsigned()->nullable(); 
        $table->foreign('team_id')->references('id')->on('teams');

        $table->string('email',45)->unique();
        // etc...

    });
}
```

Comment: I tried this before my first post. Here is the error after code modification.

SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1072 Key column 'cat_id ' doesn't exist in table (SQL: alter table users add index users_cat_id     _index(cat_id))

Comment: @SnatchIT , I updated my answer. Hope this helps. To focus on your problem/question, I omitted some of your code for clarity.

Comment: I changed my code, still no database built in Laravel.                                                                                
 SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1215 Cannot add foreign key constraint (SQ  L: alter table `users` add constraint`users_cat_id_foreign` foreign key (  `cat_id`) references `categories` (`id`))                                   
                                                                              
In Connection.php line 458:
SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1215 Cannot add foreign key constraint

Comment: I did copy/paste and have similiar error again. I am running on Homestead if that make any diffrence. Anyway ty for your help, i will rewrite my code again.

Comment: Homestead is fine.

Comment: @SnatchIT glad to help you. Did you try just to use my code? What is the new error you got?

Comment: Here is my mistake: In Connection.php line 664:
                                                                             
  SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1215 Cannot add foreign key constraint (S  
  QL: alter table `users` add constraint `users_category_id_foreign` foreig  
  n key (`category_id`) references `categories` (`id`))                      
                                                                             

In Connection.php line 458:  SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1215 Cannot add foreign key constraint

Comment: I guess the **execution order of your migrations** is not correct. Can you give me the filenames of your migration scripts?

Comment: 2014_10_12_000000_create_users_table.php 2014_10_12_100000_create_password_resets_table.php 2017_12_18_140939_create_category_table.php 2017_12_18_141956_create_team_table.php

Comment: I hope that i provide you a right information. Also i changed original users migration. I wil try now to do one by one migration.

Comment: Right! **The execution order of the migration is determined by the filename of the migration script**. In your case the users table is created before the category (which should be named categories BTW - Laravel is tricky with name conventions) and team (which should be teams) tables. The user table should be the last table created (!) - see the order in my example.

Comment: @SnatchIT , rename your tables as follows (and for now skip password_resets): 2017_12_19_0000001_create_category_table.php, 2017_12_19_0000002_create_category_team.php and 2017_12_19_0000003_create_category_table.php.   Now, the execution order will be fine.

Comment: @SnatchIT I think you are almost there, plesse keep me posted

Comment: I will have to rewrite again, but i will correct my errors in separate migrations because i builted all four tables in Laravel but they are not connected. TY one more time @iep, i will inform you when i put everything on right place.